# Why can't I hover over <a> links in the <nav>?

Tags: html, css

Whenever I hover over one of the  links in my navbar, the a:hover property doesn't seem to be working. It seems to be working fine for other  links lower on the site, but not at the top on the navbar for whatever reason.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Portfolio Website</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="first-view">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <a class="nav-links" href="#">HOME</a>
                <a class="nav-links" href="#">PORTFOLIO</a>
                <a class="nav-links" href="#">ABOUT</a>
                <a class="nav-links" href="#">CONTACT</a>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="home"> 
            <section class="first-home-section">
                <p class="name">Devon Rusinek</p>
                <p class="role">Web Developer</p>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
    <div class="second-view">
        <div id="portfolio">
            <section class="first-portfolio-section">
                <h1 class="portfolio-title">portfolio</h1>
            </section>
            <section class="second-portfolio-section">
                <p class="a-basic">ablah blah blah</p>
                <p class="b-basic">bblah blah blah</p>
                <p class="c-basic">cblah blah blah</p>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="third-view">
        <div id="about">
            <section class="first-about-section">
                <h1 class="about-title">about</h1>
            </section>
            <section class="second-about-section">
                <p class="basic">blah blah blah</p>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```
    <div class="fourth-view">
        <div id="contact">
            <section class="first-contact-section">
                <h1 class="contact-title">contact</h1>
            </section>
            <section class="second-contact-section">
                <p class="basic">blah blah blah</p>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=B612+Mono|Architects+Daughter|Catamaran|Economica|Orbitron|Noto+Serif|Sanchez|Noto+Sans+HK|Rajdhani|Monda|Courgette|Permanent+Marker|Righteous&display=swap');




/*FIRST-HOME-SECTION CHILDREN*/
.name{
    font-size: 60px;
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Architects Daughter', 'B612 Mono', monospace;
}
.role{
    font-size: 30px;
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Architects Daughter', 'B612 Mono', monospace;
}
```

```
/*A LINKS AND LISTS*/

ul{
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
}

.nav-links{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    display: inline;
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1pt black solid;
    padding: 3rem;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-family: 'B612 Mono', monospace;
   }

.nav-links:hover{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}


/*BODY*/

body{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

```
/*VIEWS*/

.first-view{
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: #FFFED6;
    height: 100vh;
}
.second-view{
    background-color: #E8E2B7;
    min-height: 30rem;
}
.third-view{
    min-height: 30rem;
    background-color: #FFFED6;
}
.fourth-view{
    min-height: 15rem;
    background-color: #E8E2B7;
}
```

```
/*SECTIONS*/

.first-home-section{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 20% 0;   
}
.first-portfolio-section{
    display: flex;
}
.second-portfolio-section{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.first-about-section{
    display: flex;
}
.first-contact-section{
    display: flex;
}
```

```
/*PARAGRAPH CONTENT*/

.basic{
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 12rem;
}
.a-basic{
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 12rem;
}
.b-basic{
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 12rem;

}
.c-basic{
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 12rem;
}
```

```
/*SECTION TITLES*/

.portfolio-title{
    font-weight: 200;
    font-family: 'B612 Mono', monospace;
    margin: 5% auto 0%;
}
.about-title{
    font-weight: 200;
    font-family: 'B612 Mono', monospace;
    margin: 5% auto 0%;
}
.contact-title{
    font-weight: 200;
    font-family: 'B612 Mono', monospace;
    margin: 5% auto 0%;
}
```

I'm expecting to get a black background and white text when I hover over in full screen mode. I am not getting any hover action however.

Answer (score 1):

If you move `z-index: -1;` from `.first-view` you will have a hover effect

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=B612+Mono|Architects+Daughter|Catamaran|Economica|Orbitron|Noto+Serif|Sanchez|Noto+Sans+HK|Rajdhani|Monda|Courgette|Permanent+Marker|Righteous&display=swap');

/*FIRST-HOME-SECTION CHILDREN*/

.name {
  font-size: 60px;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Architects Daughter', 'B612 Mono', monospace;
}

.role {
  font-size: 30px;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Architects Daughter', 'B612 Mono', monospace;
}


/*A LINKS AND LISTS*/

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

.nav-links {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  display: inline;
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1pt black solid;
  padding: 3rem;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-family: 'B612 Mono', monospace;
}

.nav-links:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}


/*BODY*/

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}


/*VIEWS*/

.first-view {
  background-color: #FFFED6;
  height: 100vh;
}

.second-view {
  background-color: #E8E2B7;
  min-height: 30rem;
}

.third-view {
  min-height: 30rem;
  background-color: #FFFED6;
}

.fourth-view {
  min-height: 15rem;
  background-color: #E8E2B7;
}


/*SECTIONS*/

.first-home-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 20% 0;
}

.first-portfolio-section {
  display: flex;
}

.second-portfolio-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.first-about-section {
  display: flex;
}

.first-contact-section {
  display: flex;
}


/*PARAGRAPH CONTENT*/

.basic {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 12rem;
}

.a-basic {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 12rem;
}

.b-basic {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 12rem;
}

.c-basic {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 12rem;
}


/*SECTION TITLES*/

.portfolio-title {
  font-weight: 200;
  font-family: 'B612 Mono', monospace;
  margin: 5% auto 0%;
}

.about-title {
  font-weight: 200;
  font-family: 'B612 Mono', monospace;
  margin: 5% auto 0%;
}

.contact-title {
  font-weight: 200;
  font-family: 'B612 Mono', monospace;
  margin: 5% auto 0%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>Portfolio Website</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="first-view">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <a class="nav-links" href="#">HOME</a>
        <a class="nav-links" href="#">PORTFOLIO</a>
        <a class="nav-links" href="#">ABOUT</a>
        <a class="nav-links" href="#">CONTACT</a>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="home">
      <section class="first-home-section">
        <p class="name">Devon Rusinek</p>
        <p class="role">Web Developer</p>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="second-view">
    <div id="portfolio">
      <section class="first-portfolio-section">
        <h1 class="portfolio-title">portfolio</h1>
      </section>
      <section class="second-portfolio-section">
        <p class="a-basic">ablah blah blah</p>
        <p class="b-basic">bblah blah blah</p>
        <p class="c-basic">cblah blah blah</p>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="third-view">
    <div id="about">
      <section class="first-about-section">
        <h1 class="about-title">about</h1>
      </section>
      <section class="second-about-section">
        <p class="basic">blah blah blah</p>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="fourth-view">
    <div id="contact">
      <section class="first-contact-section">
        <h1 class="contact-title">contact</h1>
      </section>
      <section class="second-contact-section">
        <p class="basic">blah blah blah</p>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The z-index in `.first-view` is pushing the whole `div` to the back of the stacking context. Remove the `z-index`or give it a higher value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is being caused by the `z-index` in your `first-view` div that's wrapping your navbar.

If you remove that property from your css then you'll be able to hover over the nav links as expected.